# Error "geom_line(): Each group consists of only one observation. ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" (line graph - repeated measures design)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, reshape, devtools

I am trying to plot a line graph for two independent variables.

Here are where I downloaded the data and how I converted them to a long format:

```
textMessages <- read.delim("http://www.discoveringstatistics.com/docs/ds_data_files/R%20Data%20Files/TextMessages.dat", header = TRUE)
write.table(textMessages, "Text Messages.csv", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

textMessagesLong <- melt(textMessages, id = "Group", measured = c("Baseline", "Six_months"))
```

In brief, my dataset contains 25 students whose access to cell phones was restricted and 25 students who were encouraged to use text messages every day, both for a six-month period.
Each group was given a grammar test before the intervention (i.e., Baseline) and after the intervention (i.e., Six_Month). The "value" variable contains the grammar test scores of each participant at a given time point, and the "Group" variable contains the participants' group (i.e., either " Text Messager" or "Controls"). Below is the dataframe I am working with:

```
> textMessagesLong
             Group   variable value
1   Text Messagers   Baseline    52
2   Text Messagers   Baseline    68
3   Text Messagers   Baseline    85
4   Text Messagers   Baseline    47
5   Text Messagers   Baseline    73
6   Text Messagers   Baseline    57
7   Text Messagers   Baseline    63
8   Text Messagers   Baseline    50
9   Text Messagers   Baseline    66
10  Text Messagers   Baseline    60
11  Text Messagers   Baseline    51
12  Text Messagers   Baseline    72
13  Text Messagers   Baseline    77
14  Text Messagers   Baseline    57
15  Text Messagers   Baseline    79
16  Text Messagers   Baseline    75
17  Text Messagers   Baseline    53
18  Text Messagers   Baseline    72
19  Text Messagers   Baseline    62
20  Text Messagers   Baseline    71
21  Text Messagers   Baseline    53
22  Text Messagers   Baseline    64
23  Text Messagers   Baseline    79
24  Text Messagers   Baseline    75
25  Text Messagers   Baseline    60
26        Controls   Baseline    65
27        Controls   Baseline    57
28        Controls   Baseline    66
29        Controls   Baseline    71
30        Controls   Baseline    75
31        Controls   Baseline    61
32        Controls   Baseline    80
33        Controls   Baseline    66
34        Controls   Baseline    53
35        Controls   Baseline    62
36        Controls   Baseline    61
37        Controls   Baseline    77
38        Controls   Baseline    66
39        Controls   Baseline    52
40        Controls   Baseline    60
41        Controls   Baseline    58
42        Controls   Baseline    54
43        Controls   Baseline    72
44        Controls   Baseline    71
45        Controls   Baseline    87
46        Controls   Baseline    75
47        Controls   Baseline    57
48        Controls   Baseline    59
49        Controls   Baseline    46
50        Controls   Baseline    89
51  Text Messagers Six_months    32
52  Text Messagers Six_months    48
53  Text Messagers Six_months    62
54  Text Messagers Six_months    16
55  Text Messagers Six_months    63
56  Text Messagers Six_months    53
57  Text Messagers Six_months    59
58  Text Messagers Six_months    58
59  Text Messagers Six_months    59
60  Text Messagers Six_months    57
61  Text Messagers Six_months    60
62  Text Messagers Six_months    56
63  Text Messagers Six_months    61
64  Text Messagers Six_months    52
65  Text Messagers Six_months     9
66  Text Messagers Six_months    76
67  Text Messagers Six_months    38
68  Text Messagers Six_months    63
69  Text Messagers Six_months    53
70  Text Messagers Six_months    61
71  Text Messagers Six_months    50
72  Text Messagers Six_months    78
73  Text Messagers Six_months    33
74  Text Messagers Six_months    68
75  Text Messagers Six_months    59
76        Controls Six_months    62
77        Controls Six_months    50
78        Controls Six_months    62
79        Controls Six_months    61
80        Controls Six_months    70
81        Controls Six_months    64
82        Controls Six_months    64
83        Controls Six_months    55
84        Controls Six_months    47
85        Controls Six_months    61
86        Controls Six_months    56
87        Controls Six_months    64
88        Controls Six_months    62
89        Controls Six_months    47
90        Controls Six_months    56
91        Controls Six_months    78
92        Controls Six_months    74
93        Controls Six_months    61
94        Controls Six_months    61
95        Controls Six_months    78
96        Controls Six_months    62
97        Controls Six_months    71
98        Controls Six_months    55
99        Controls Six_months    46
100       Controls Six_months    79
```

in 'dput()' format:

```
> dput(textMessagesLong)
structure(list(Group = c("Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", "Text Messagers", 
"Text Messagers", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", "Controls", 
"Controls", "Controls", "Controls"), variable = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = c("Baseline", 
"Six_months"), class = "factor"), value = c(52L, 68L, 85L, 47L, 
73L, 57L, 63L, 50L, 66L, 60L, 51L, 72L, 77L, 57L, 79L, 75L, 53L, 
72L, 62L, 71L, 53L, 64L, 79L, 75L, 60L, 65L, 57L, 66L, 71L, 75L, 
61L, 80L, 66L, 53L, 62L, 61L, 77L, 66L, 52L, 60L, 58L, 54L, 72L, 
71L, 87L, 75L, 57L, 59L, 46L, 89L, 32L, 48L, 62L, 16L, 63L, 53L, 
59L, 58L, 59L, 57L, 60L, 56L, 61L, 52L, 9L, 76L, 38L, 63L, 53L, 
61L, 50L, 78L, 33L, 68L, 59L, 62L, 50L, 62L, 61L, 70L, 64L, 64L, 
55L, 47L, 61L, 56L, 64L, 62L, 47L, 56L, 78L, 74L, 61L, 61L, 78L, 
62L, 71L, 55L, 46L, 79L)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I converted the "variable" variable to a factor with levels called "Baseline" and "Six_Months", to ensure that "variable" is a grouping variable:

```
textMessagesLong$variable <- factor(textMessagesLong$variable, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Baseline", "Six_months"))
```

I then executed the following code block to plot the mean test scores for each "variable" on the x-axis for each "Group":

```
textMessagesLine <- ggplot(textMessagesLong, aes(variable, value, color = Group))
textMessagesLine + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "line", aes(group = Group))
```

However, I am getting the following error "`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

I was expecting to get a line graph for each group where the baseline mean and the six-months mean are plotted as points within each group (controls or text messagers) connected by a line.

Instead, I am getting this:

[image]

Where the x-axis is not showing the variables "Baseline" and "Six_months", but instead shows N/A.

I am suspecting this is due to the computer not recognizing each line as a unique entity. There is something I am missing here. Do single vs. repeated measure designs require different approaches when plotting line graphs?

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(textMessagesLong)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(textMessagesLong, 20))`.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the data (ideally using `dput()`) instead of as images - it makes it much easier for others to help you if we can run your code.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I apologize for my ignorance here—I am pretty new to this. I removed screenshots of the data frame and added it in {}.

Comment: @nrennie Sure, I added the data in dput() format.

Comment: Your `dput` shows that `textMessagesLong$variable` only has NAs. When you are converting to factor, I think you are overwriting with NAs because you don't have the levels 1 and 2 in the data. Carefully read `?factor`.

Comment: @Axeman, you're brilliant! :) Now I see what's happening here. I appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for updating your question with the data, and best of luck with your analyses!